# Getting a joystick's path in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, game-controller

On Linux, I can access my joystick with the following path: `/dev/input/js0`

Is there a similar way I can access my joystick on Windows?

Comment: It might help to say exactly what you need to do. Windows and linux handle devices very differently

Answer (score 0):

It might be accessible under the `\\?\Device\` tree, check with [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx). However, not all Windows APIs are able to access "files" under `\\.\` and `\\?\`, so this won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey can access the joystick](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) which you can use to [trigger keyboard shortcuts](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm) and macros etc.